# What will happen with ubuntu if I reset Windows 8 to factory default?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 on my hp laptop. I have been using this for over a year, but recently, there was some accident after which my Windows 8 is not booting.

I tried to do a system refresh, but that is broken too. Now, I am planning to do a reset to factory defaults, but I am not sure what will happen with my Ubuntu partition.

I have done a system refresh before, and it did not wipe my Ubuntu partition, only wrote over the grub2, which I got back easily. But I am unsure with resetting.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be positive of what any specific utility will do, but as a general rule, a "factory reset" utility is likely to ***COMPLETELY WIPE YOUR DISK, INCLUDING YOUR UBUNTU INSTALLATION.*** Less radical repair utilities won't do this, but you must be *very* cautious about anything designed to restore the computer to its original factory state.

Instead of running a "factory reset" utility, you might consider obtaining a generic Windows installation image and use it to re-install Windows the "manual" way. This should be a bit safer, and will set up Windows without whatever bloatware your computer's manufacturer has foisted upon you. You can obtain Windows installation media legally from Microsoft; see [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/), or do a Web search on "obtain Windows legally" or similar terms, to learn how.

Note that even re-installing Windows manually is not risk-free; a slipup or bug could end up wiping out Ubuntu. Thus, backing up your personal files is ***highly*** recommended. Keeping such a backup up-to-date in the future will help protect you against unexpected random problems -- disk hardware failures, accidents involving disk-partitioning or other low-level disk-access software, mistakes with `rm` or other file-removal tools, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect Ubuntu unless and until you will not gone a wipe that(Ubuntu) drive.

In worse case it may remove your grub loader, but that can be restore easily.

Answer (score 0):

once you reset the windows then windows never touch unix paration in your condition.

once you completed the windows reset than might be possibility that 1. you have grub with windows And ubuntu menu on start up

2. if you have no duel boot menu than you have To use ubuntu rescue disk and repair the boot menu.

this will help you lot more but again want To say be careful with my instruction i am not liable for any cause or damage to you.

this will work all the time for me.